# how to scrape data from sub links inside a Wikipedia article?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to scrape data form sub-links present within a Wikipedia article

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import re
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_gas').read()
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')
links = soup.find("div",{"id" : "bodyContent"}).findAll("a" , href=re.compile("(/wiki/)+([A-Za-z0-9_:()])+"))

for link in links:
    print(link['href'])
    webpage=urllib.request.urlopen(link['href'])
    soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(webpage,'lxml')
```

Comment: What is the issue, here? Yes, it's "possible to scrape data form sub-links present within a Wikipedia article"; what's wrong/what's the traceback you get when running the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `links` list contains the *ends* of the URLs you're looking to scrape. Running your code, I received a `ValueError: unknown url type: '/wiki/Wikipedia:Pending_changes'`. So to solve what I think i

```
s your issue, try this:

beg_link = 'http://www.wikipedia.com'

for link in links:
    full_link = beg_link + link['href']
    print(full_link)
    webpage=urllib.request.urlopen(full_link)
    soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(webpage,'lxml')
```

Which prints and results in:

```
http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/Wikipedia:Pending_changes
http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/GHG_(disambiguation)
http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/File:Greenhouse_Effect.svg
...
```

Comment: But when i try to visit those pages with the above code  it shows error

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to follow links and retrieve more links. To do so you can use a recursive function (a function that calls itself). You should also set a limit on the number of links you retrieve or your program will not stop, and you should check you haven't visited a link already:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib2
import re


def get_links(links, url, limit=100):
    sauce = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki' + url).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')
    pos = len(links)
    for link in soup.find("div",{"id" : "bodyContent"}).findAll("a" , href=re.compile("(/wiki/)+([A-Za-z0-9_:()])+")):
        if len(links) < limit and link['href'] not in links:
            links.append(link['href'])
    if len(links) < limit:
        for url in links[pos:]:
            get_links(links, url, limit)


def main():
    links = []
    get_links(links, '/Greenhouse_gas')
    print links

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```